# How to convert a dataframe of dictionaries into a dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a `information` dataframe that I obtained in the following way:

```
information = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(docs.json()["hits"]["hits"])
```

`information` contains objects of type `news`. For each news I only want `_source`:

```
    _id                                         _index            _score     _source                                            _type
0   c0b0773f94fc91938709edccf1ec4e3039e7576b    luxurynsight_v2 6.023481    {'importer': 'APItay', 'releasedAt': 147621242...   news
1   9ce6d7e015dc28497ff8ccd4915cf4104188107d    luxurynsight_v2 6.015883    {'importer': 'APItay', 'releasedAt': 152717820...   news
...
```

And inside of each `_source` I only want `name` and `createAt`

For example here is one of the `news`:

```
_index  _type   _id _score  _source
_headers    luxurynsight_v2 news    c0b0773f94fc91938709edccf1ec4e3039e7576b    6.023481    [{'header': 'date', 'value': 'Fri, 23 Feb 2018...
_opengraph  luxurynsight_v2 news    c0b0773f94fc91938709edccf1ec4e3039e7576b    6.023481    [{'header': 'og_locale', 'value': 'en_US'}, {'...
_sums   luxurynsight_v2 news    c0b0773f94fc91938709edccf1ec4e3039e7576b    6.023481    [{'sum': 'decfedbfae938da88e93e75c7ebb4dc9', '...
_tags   luxurynsight_v2 news    c0b0773f94fc91938709edccf1ec4e3039e7576b    6.023481    [{'visible': True, 'name': 'Gucci', 'count': 3...
_users  luxurynsight_v2 news    c0b0773f94fc91938709edccf1ec4e3039e7576b    6.023481    [{'permission': 'public', 'id': 0}]
archive luxurynsight_v2 news    c0b0773f94fc91938709edccf1ec4e3039e7576b    6.023481    True
authors luxurynsight_v2 news    c0b0773f94fc91938709edccf1ec4e3039e7576b    6.023481    []
catalogs    luxurynsight_v2 news    c0b0773f94fc91938709edccf1ec4e3039e7576b    6.023481    [Luxurynsight]
cleanUrl    luxurynsight_v2 news    c0b0773f94fc91938709edccf1ec4e3039e7576b    6.023481    http://www.cpp-luxury.com/gucci-debuts-art-ins...
contentType luxurynsight_v2 news    c0b0773f94fc91938709edccf1ec4e3039e7576b    6.023481    text/html
createdAt   luxurynsight_v2 news    c0b0773f94fc91938709edccf1ec4e3039e7576b    6.023481    1508510973592
domain  luxurynsight_v2 news    c0b0773f94fc91938709edccf1ec4e3039e7576b    6.023481    www.cpp-luxury.com
excerpt luxurynsight_v2 news    c0b0773f94fc91938709edccf1ec4e3039e7576b    6.023481    Gucci debuts art installation at its Ginza sto...
foundOn luxurynsight_v2 news    c0b0773f94fc91938709edccf1ec4e3039e7576b    6.023481    [excerpt, name]
iframe  luxurynsight_v2 news    c0b0773f94fc91938709edccf1ec4e3039e7576b    6.023481    True
importer    luxurynsight_v2 news    c0b0773f94fc91938709edccf1ec4e3039e7576b    6.023481    APItay
language    luxurynsight_v2 news    c0b0773f94fc91938709edccf1ec4e3039e7576b    6.023481    en-US
name    luxurynsight_v2 news    c0b0773f94fc91938709edccf1ec4e3039e7576b    6.023481    Gucci debuts art installation at its Ginza sto...
plainCategories luxurynsight_v2 news    c0b0773f94fc91938709edccf1ec4e3039e7576b    6.023481    [AutomaticBrands, Market, AutomaticPeople, Tag]
plainTags   luxurynsight_v2 news    c0b0773f94fc91938709edccf1ec4e3039e7576b    6.023481    [Gucci, Market_Japan, Alessandro Michele, Tag_...
previewImage    luxurynsight_v2 news    c0b0773f94fc91938709edccf1ec4e3039e7576b    6.023481    http://www.cpp-luxury.com/wp-content/uploads/2...
publishedAt luxurynsight_v2 news    c0b0773f94fc91938709edccf1ec4e3039e7576b    6.023481    1476212420000
```

The expected result is:

```
createAt    names
2007-01-01  What Sticks from '06. Somalia Orders Islamist...
2007-01-02  Heart Health: Vitamin Does Not Prevent Death ...
2007-01-03  Google Answer to Filling Jobs Is an Algorithm...
```

#### My attempt

```
>>> information._source
0    {'importer': 'APItay', 'releasedAt': 147621242...
1    {'importer': 'APItay', 'releasedAt': 152717820...
2    {'importer': 'APItay', 'releasedAt': 152418240...
```

The problem is that we get a dataframe of dictionaries. How to transform it into a dataframe? Or maybe there are other ways?

#### I also tried ...

```
import ast
information._source = information._source.apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x))

# Store in a new column
df['name'] = information._source.apply(lambda x: x['name'])

# Store in a new column
df['createAt'] = information._source.apply(lambda x: x['createAt'])
```

But it gives me a ValueError :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-194-968302937df5> in <module>
      1 import ast
----> 2 information._source = information._source.apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x))
      3 
      4 # Store in a new column
      5 df['name'] = information._source.apply(lambda x: x['name'])

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   3192             else:
   3193                 values = self.astype(object).values
-> 3194                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   3195 
   3196         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas/_libs/src\inference.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-194-968302937df5> in <lambda>(x)
      1 import ast
----> 2 information._source = information._source.apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x))
      3 
      4 # Store in a new column
      5 df['name'] = information._source.apply(lambda x: x['name'])

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\ast.py in literal_eval(node_or_string)
     83                     return left - right
     84         raise ValueError('malformed node or string: ' + repr(node))
---> 85     return _convert(node_or_string)
     86 
     87 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\ast.py in _convert(node)
     82                 else:
     83                     return left - right
---> 84         raise ValueError('malformed node or string: ' + repr(node))
     85     return _convert(node_or_string)
     86 

ValueError: malformed node or string: {'importer': 'APItay', 'releasedAt': 1476212420000, '_tags': [{'visible': True, 'name': 'Gucci', 'count': 39, 'id': 'Gucci', 'category': ['AutomaticBrands']}, {'visible': False, 'name': 'MLI1', 'count': 39, 'id': 'staffTagging_MLI1', 'category': ['staffTagging']}, {'visible': True, 'name': 'Japan', 'count': 19, 'id': 'Market_Japan', 'category': ['Market']}, {'visible': False, 'name': 'KBN', 'count': 4, 'id': 'staffTagging_KBN', 'category': ['staffTagging']}, {'visible': False, 'name': 'JLE',
```

#### Data

```
def create_doc(uri, doc_data={}):
    """Create new document."""
    query = json.dumps(doc_data)
    response = requests.post(uri, data = query)#data=json.dumps({"size":10}))
    print(type(response))
    return(response)

doc_data = {
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must" : [
       {"term":{"text":"gucci"}}
     ]
    }
  }
 }

docs = create_doc("https://XXXX@db.luxurynsight.com/luxurynsight_v2/news/_search",doc_data)
```

Comment: Do you have a small datasample for testing? Maybe if you add the column's values (`information._source.values`) into another variable as dict and then to dataframe?

Comment: @mrbTT Yes, I just added the way to reach the data, it's an elasticsearch database.

Comment: I'm having trouble connecting to the elasticsearch and I believe it's a proxy/firewall setting from where I'm at because I can access the file via browser. Saving the content to .txt how do you import it as the df?

Comment: @mrbTT Yes, [here](https://api.jsonbin.io/b/5c40949b81fe89272a8e6cba) it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verified answer for your updated question -

```
# Reading the JSON file
df = pd.read_json('file.json')

# Converting the element wise _source feature datatype to dictionary
df._source = df._source.apply(lambda x: dict(x))

# Creating name column
df['name'] = df._source.apply(lambda x: x['name'])

# Creating createdAt column
df['createdAt'] = df._source.apply(lambda x: x['createdAt'])
```

**Sample Output**
[image: Sample Output]

Comment: Isn't it `_source`rather than `source_` ? I tried your attempt, and showed the output in my question, but I had a ValueError.

Comment: Yup, it's a small typo. It's `_source`

Comment: The ValueError was independent from the underscore one ; )

Comment: @ThePassenger what is your expected output. I see in your post, first you mention `name` and `createAt` later in your expected output you have `articles`. Can you clarify?

Comment: @ThePassenger I've updated and also verified the answer.

Comment: Haaa ! Great ! I've updated the expected output which had weird named

Comment: My above solution has arrived on your expected output. You only have to convert the unix timestamp back to human readable format.

Comment: Yes, I'm testing it with the dynamic dataframe but have the ValueError still.